# BASH: Dollar sign substitution after a hash?

Tags: bash, substitution

I am writing a script that deals with hex color values and I want to substitute in a user provided variable after a hash mark like so:

```
HEX=$1
COLOR='#$HEX'
```

But this fails as I believe it is interpreting the hash as a comment?  How do I escape the hash so that I can have a variable which contains a string with a hash in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That fails because you're using single quotes. There's no variable substitution inside single quotes. Instead, use double quoted:

```
COLOR="#$HEX"
```

Comment: Ah yes!  I don't know why I always forget this distinction.  Thank you !

Answer (score 4):

Single quotes block dollar interpolation. Double ones don't, so this should work:

```
COLOR="#$HEX"
```